# How to predict values with a trained Tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, save, restore

I've trained my NN in Tensorflow and saved the model like this:

```
def neural_net(x):
   layer_1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=x, units=195, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
   out_layer = tf.layers.dense(inputs=layer_1, units=6)
   return out_layer

train_x = pd.read_csv("data_x.csv", sep=" ")
train_y = pd.read_csv("data_y.csv", sep=" ")
train_x = train_x / 6 - 0.5

train_size = 0.9
train_cnt = int(floor(train_x.shape[0] * train_size))
x_train = train_x.iloc[0:train_cnt].values
y_train = train_y.iloc[0:train_cnt].values
x_test = train_x.iloc[train_cnt:].values
y_test = train_y.iloc[train_cnt:].values

x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 386])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 6])

nn_output = neural_net(x)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y, predictions=nn_output))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)

training_epochs = 5000
display_step = 1000
batch_size = 30

keep_prob = tf.placeholder("float")

saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        total_batch = int(len(x_train) / batch_size)
        x_batches = np.array_split(x_train, total_batch)
        y_batches = np.array_split(y_train, total_batch)
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = x_batches[i], y_batches[i]
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], 
                            feed_dict={
                                x: batch_x, 
                                y: batch_y, 
                                keep_prob: 0.8
                            })
    saver.save(sess, 'trained_model', global_step=1000)
```

Now I want to use the trained model in a different file. Of course there are many many examples of restoring and saving the model, I went through lots of them. Still I couldn't make any of them work, there is always some kind of error. So this is my restore file, could you please help me to make it restore the saved model?

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('trained_model-1000.meta')
y_pred = []
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
    sess.run([y_pred], feed_dict={x: input_values})
```

E.g. this attempt gave me the error "The session graph is empty. Add operations to the graph before calling run()." So what operation should I add to the graph and how? I don't know what that operation should be in my model... I don't understand this whole concept of saving/restoring in Tensorflow. Or should I do the restoring completely differently? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried putting `saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('trained_model-1000.meta')` within the `with tf.Session() as sess:` ? Maybe with `tf.reset_default_graph()` before that just to be sure...

Comment: Hi, yes, it's solved this particular error, thanks. But the model is still not properly restored. I updated the code so there's more context.

Comment: Or maybe it is restored, but I just don't know how to use it to make new predictions.

Comment: @T.Poe Are there any updates on how to handle this?

Comment: @LowYieldBond You have to define `neural_net(x)` the same way as in the training file, then restore its data the way like in my question or in the CAta.RAy's answer below. Then you predict like in Alli Abbasi's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Forgive me if I am wrong but `tf.train.Saver()` only saves the variable values not the graph itself. This means that if you want to load the model in a different file you need to rebuild the graph or somehow load the graph as well. Tensorflow documentation states:

> The tf.train.Saver object not only saves variables to checkpoint files, it also restores variables. Note that when you restore variables from a file you do not have to initialize them beforehand.

Consider the following example:

One file that saves the model:

```
# Create some variables.
v1 = tf.get_variable("v1", shape=[3], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer) 
v2 = tf.get_variable("v2", shape=[5], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)

inc_v1 = v1.assign(v1+1)
dec_v2 = v2.assign(v2-1)

# Add an op to initialize the variables.
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Add ops to save and restore all the variables.
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# Later, launch the model, initialize the variables, do some work, and save the
# variables to disk.
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    # Do some work with the model.
    inc_v1.op.run()
    dec_v2.op.run()
    # Save the variables to disk.
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
    print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
```

The other file that loads the previously saved model:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

# Create some variables.
v1 = tf.get_variable("v1", shape=[3])
v2 = tf.get_variable("v2", shape=[5])

# Add ops to save and restore all the variables.
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# Later, launch the model, use the saver to restore variables from disk, and
# do some work with the model.
with tf.Session() as sess:
   # Restore variables from disk.
   saver.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
   print("Model restored.")
   # Check the values of the variables
   print("v1 : %s" % v1.eval())
   print("v2 : %s" % v2.eval())
```

Comment: Thanks for response! This seems like lots of other examples I saw elsewhere. There are these variables `v1, v2` which are saved, then read. I understand this. What I don't get is what is this saved 'variable' in my code?  I updated the code so there is more context.

Comment: What saved variable? When save a model, it only saves the values assigned to each tensorflow value in the current session. If you want to restore that model in another session you will have to rebuild the graph in that session. If the answer was useful please mark it an answer a lot of time goes into answering these questions ;)

Comment: As I said, your code is an example exactly same as dozens of others (actually copy paste from the original tensorflow tutorial which of course I've seen already). But I still do not know "How to predict  values with a trained model" which is the original question, so I can't mark it as an answer, still thank you.

Comment: @LasseJacobs You mean if I want to rebuild the model in another session, I have to rewrite all the codes building the graph? Like "x=tf.placeholder(something)" and "layer = tf.nn.conv2d(input=x)"? Is there any way that I can also load the graph structure from files?

Answer (score 0):

```
 output = sess.run(nn_output, feed_dict={ x: batch_x, keep_prob: 0.8 })
```

Where `nn_output` is the name is the output variable of the last layer of you network. You can save you variable using:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver([nn_output])
saver.save(sess, 'my_test_model',global_step=1000) # save every 1000 steps
```

and therefore in your code:

```
out_layer = tf.layers.dense(inputs=layer_1, units=6)
```

should be :

```
out_layer = tf.layers.dense(inputs=layer_1, units=6, name='nn_output')
```

**To restore:**

```
with tf.Session() as sess:    
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('my_test_model')
saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
```

Now you should have access to that node of the graph. If the name is not specified, it is difficult to recover that particular layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can know use `tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder` function.

The main lines for the saving:

```
builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(graph_location)

builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess, ["cnn_mnist"])

builder.save()
```

A code to save the model :

```
...
def main(_):
  # Import data
  mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir)

  # Create the model
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

  # Define loss and optimizer
  y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None])

  # Build the graph for the deep net
  y_conv, keep_prob = deepnn(x) # an unknow model model

  with tf.name_scope('loss'):
    cross_entropy = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(
        labels=y_, logits=y_conv)
  cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)

  with tf.name_scope('adam_optimizer'):
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)

  with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), y_)
    correct_prediction = tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32)
  accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(correct_prediction)

  graph_location ="tmp/"
  print('Saving graph to: %s' % graph_location)
  **builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(graph_location)**

  train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(graph_location)
  train_writer.add_graph(tf.get_default_graph())

  saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=1)

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    **builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess, ["cnn_mnist"])**
    for i in range(20000):
      batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
      if i % 100 == 0:
        train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
            x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
        print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy))
      train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

    print('test accuracy %g' % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
        x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))

    **builder.save()**
    saver.save(sess, "tmp/my_checkpoint.ckpt", global_step =0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('--data_dir', type=str,
                      default='/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data',
                      help='Directory for storing input data')
  FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
`
```

A code to restore the model :

```
import tensorflow as tf

# récupération des poids 

export_dir = "tmp"
sess = tf.Session()
tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess,["cnn_mnist"], export_dir)

#trainable_var = tf.trainable_variables()
trainable_var = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)
for var in trainable_var:
    print(var.name)`
```

Comment: after that you can use the checkpoints to restore the weights properly ...

Answer (score 0):

This question is old. But if someone else is struggling with doing predictions with a trained model (with TF 1.x) this code might help.

Pay attention that

1. Your network construction/defining code must be executed before the `Saver()` instance is created. Otherwise you get the error: `ValueError: No variables to save`. In the code below the `LeNet(x)` method constructs the network for input placeholder `x`.
2. **You should *not* initialize the variables in the session.** Because obviously you are loading them from the saved model.

```py
# all the network construction code
# (e.g. defining the variables and layers)
# must be exectured before the creation of 
# the Saver() object. Otherwise you get the 
# error: ValueError: No variables to save. 

logits = LeNet(x)
saver = tf.train.Saver()

index = random.randint(0, len(X_train))
image = X_train[index].squeeze()
label = y_train[index]
print("Label: ", label)

plt.figure(figsize=(1,1))
plt.imshow(image, cmap="gray")
plt.show()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./checkpoints/'))
    logits_output = sess.run(logits, feed_dict={x: image.reshape((1, 32, 32, 1))}) 
    logits_output = logits_output.squeeze()
    pred_output = np.exp(logits_output)/sum(np.exp(logits_output)) #softmax
    print("Logits: ", logits_output)
    print("Prediction output:", pred_output)
    print("Predicted Label: ", np.argmax(pred_output))
```